# Interrupt programming PIC18F4520 :: Toggling LED

Tags: microcontroller, pic, interrupts

[image: upright picture]
<sub>[Edit: replaced sideways photo with upright photo]</sub>
I recently started using interrupts in pic programming. I started with this program but I am not able to go through what has been done in this program???

I want to know that :

**Why PORTC and PORTD have been defined as INPUT and OUTPUT respectively ?**

**What is 0x08 (Interrupt location) ?**

**Why to enable timer interrupt , if we are not using it ?**

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Seriously? Type out the code in your post. A picture of code is bad enough, a sideways picture... I just don't know anymore.

Comment: @uint128_t.. thanks i have uploaded upright picture... Can you please tell now??

Answer (score 3):

This code seems to be from the book: `PIC Microcontroller and Embedded Systems: Using Assembly and C for PIC18`

> Why PORTC and PORTD have been defined as INPUT and OUTPUT respectively ?

That is explained 1 page earlier in your book, before the previous assembler version of the same code. The author says: "Program 11-4 connects a switch to INT0 [shown in figure 11-9 as being pin RB0] and an LED to pin RB7.  In this program, every time INT0 is activated, it toggles the LED, **while at the same time data is being transferred from PORTC to PORTD**." [My bold]

So the answer to your question, is that this is what the book's authors decided to do in their sample program. This could be trying to show that the main loop (which is simply that `PORTD=PORTC;` statement) does not need to be concerned with what happens in the ISR to handle the LED toggling, for example.

> What is 0x08 (Interrupt location) ?

This is explained in chapter 11 of the book and in the PIC18 documentation. In short, it is the address defined in the PIC18 architecture, to hold the ISR (or a jump to the ISR) for the PIC18 "High Priority" interrupt.

> Why to enable timer interrupt , if we are not using it ?

That is a mistake in the comment (not the code), in the book's *C* listing.  That line says:

```
INTCONbits.INT0IE=1;  enable Timer0 interrupt
```

Compare that with the *assembler* version on the previous page, which says:

```
BSF INTCON,INT0IE    ; enable INT0 interrupt
```

which is actually the correct comment - pin RB0 triggers INT0, and as the author mentions, their description is that a switch is attached to pin RB0. Hence, for that switch to cause an interrupt, the code needs to enable INT0 as an interrupt source. Read chapter 11 carefully, where this is explained.

*If* the *comment* in the C source line was correct about enabling the Timer0 interrupt, the correct C code would be: `INTCONbits.TMR0IE=1;`. Therefore the *code* in that line in the book (`INTCONbits.INT0IE=1;`) is showing you that the *comment* part of that line ("enable Timer0 interrupt") is wrong.

Edit: I couldn't find any official errata webpage for this book, however I saw these comments on two Amazon reviews for the book:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/PIC-Microcontroller-Using-Assembly-PIC18/dp/0136009026

> Warning! This book contains many inaccuracies. I've only finished the
>   first two chapters but I already have serious concerns about using
>   this book.

and

> Beware, this book has some serious errors in at least the stepper
>   motor schematics. [...] My concern here is that you will damage your
>   pic et al if wired as indicated. These sort of errors ought never to
>   have made it to print.